# compare lists of strings and remove any that are similar - python

Tags: python, string, list

For example:

```
List1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

List2 = [3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

and I would like it to return `[8,9]` because 3,4,5,6 and 7 are in both lists.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return list(set(List1) - set(List2))
```